# what's the catch (select new in LINQ vs simply filling the object)

Tags: sql-server, linq, exception

can someone please explain the difference between these 2 pieces of code:

```
var temp = (from c in Context.SomeTable 
            select new SomeObject { name=c.Name, created = c.Created}).ToList();
```

and this :

```
var temp = (from c in Context.SomeTable select c);
foreach(SomeTable t in temp)
{
SomeObject so = new SomeObject();
so.name = t.Name;
so.created = t.Created;
}
```

`SomeTable.Created` is a nullable datetime type field in the database.

While the first piece throws an exception:

```
Sqldatetime overflow. must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 am and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 pm.
```

the second one works.

Thank You!

Comment: Could you post the declaration of SomeObject?

Comment: Are you getting the exception in the pieces of code you have here, or do you modify and then submit changes back to the database, and you get it at that point?

Comment: And the schema for SomeTable too - is Created a datetime in the database, or a varchar of some sort?

Comment: hi. thx for reply.
it's simple class

public SomeObject
{
  string _name;
  public string name { get {return _name;} set{_name=value;} }

  DateTime _created;
  public DateTime created { get {return _created;} set{_created =value;} }
}

Comment: nope, i dont modify or submit any changes, just making select

Comment: The edmx file originally was created with sql server 2008 ( dont get that exception with it ), but then we moved our db to sql server 2005,
thats where the problems started

Comment: Can you paste the actual definition of "SomeTable"? ie. go and copy the code from the source and paste it into the question? The reason I suspect you haven't really done this is that "public SomeObject" is missing the keyword "class", and I suspect you also have some [Column(...)] attributes in the generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code no `c` will be read from `SomeTable` or instance of `SomeObject` will be created until something enumerates `temp`.

The second this enumeration takes place.

Therefore I would expect there is an issue with the validity of `Context.SomeTable` when `temp` is enumerated in the first case.

Test this by changing the first block to:

```
var temp = (from c in Context.SomeTable 
            select new SomeObject { name=c.Name, created = c.Created}
           ).ToList();
```

which forces immediate enumeration.

Comment: Since he gets an exception from the first piece of code, I'd say it is safe to assume he's actually executing the query.

Comment: yep, srry. forgot to add .ToList() in my post.
i had it too originally.

Comment: So did you get an answer to your question or not? It sounds to me as you already did what this answer said you should do, but still have the problem, yet you've marked it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Lasse: "safe to assume [...]": See my third paragraph, between creating the IQueryable<T> and enumerating it something changed.